# distinct occurrences count in pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe 'df' with three columns.
i wish to display the distinct IP's and total instances with respect to them.

```
       Name   IP                       Instances 
       amy   172.16.1.98               2
       amy   172.16.1.98               1
       amy   172.16.1.98               1
       amy  172.16.2.239               2
       amy  172.16.2.239               2
       amy  172.16.2.239              112
       amy  172.16.2.239               1
       amy   172.16.3.39               2
       amy   172.16.3.39               1
       amy   172.16.3.39               1
```

output ex-
172.16.3.39     4,
172.16.2.239   117  etc...

I am new to pandas any help would be of great use.

Comment: Use `df.groupby('IP', as_index=False)['Instances'].sum()`

Comment: thanks a lot ..! 
can you recommend any cheat sheet. i am new to this :D

Comment: No problem, nice day :) Btw, what about [Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) ?

Comment: thanks again... you rock :D